# How to use Authorization & Capture correct way in woocommerce store

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, woocommerce, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am currently developing a website for my client and he needs "Authorization & Capture" payment from paypal in his cart.

I have seen that the woocommerce give " PayPal standard " option to their store, and i am confused that Authorization & Capture can be added to paypal standard?

If no, then how can i add it to my site?

Comment: Hi I got this working with the standard paypal settings from WooCommerce no extra plugins needed. There is no option by default but I can add it for you send me an email http://bit.ly/UHR2WS

Answer (score 1):

You can process Payment Standard transactions as an Authorization. You need to define the variable `paymentaction` in the code you're passing to PayPal and set the value to `authorization`.

You'll then need to submit `DoCapture` API calls to complete the payment or capture them manually through your account.

I don't know what options are in Woocommerce so I can't be sure if they have an option for it but it is possible to process Payment Standard transactions as an Authorization.